# Understanding the concept of "dynamical coupling" between measures in the Villani's book

Tags: measure-theory, probability-distributions, metric-spaces, optimal-transport, coupling

I am currently studying the geodesics in the space of probability measures over a Polish space (complete and separable metric space). In the "Optimal Transport - Old and new" book of C. Villani, there's the definition 7.19 (page 126) of "dynamical coupling":

"Definition: Let $(\mathcal{X},d)$ be a Polish space. A dynamical transference plan $\Pi$ is a probability measure on the space $C([0,1],\mathcal{X})$. A dynamical coupling of two probability measures $\mu_0,\mu_1\in\mathscr{P}(\mathcal{X})$ is a random curve $\gamma:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathcal{X}$ such that $\mathrm{law}\,(\gamma_0)=\mu_0$, $\mathrm{law}\,(\gamma_1)=\mu_1$."

What I don't understand is the concept of $\textit{random curve}$: why can we talk about "laws" of the curve? To me it seems that $\gamma$ is just an usual curve over a metric space!

Thank you for your replies in advance!

Comment: Roughly speaking, a random curve $\gamma : [0,1] \to X$ is a one-parameter family of random variables $\{\gamma(t)\}_{t \in [0,1]}$, each one taking values in $X$.  Each of these random variables has a law.  In your quotation, $\mu_{0}$ is the law of $\gamma(0)$ and $\mu_{1}$ is the law of $\gamma(1)$.  (A nice way of making this tidier is to work with probability measures on $C([0,1];X)$, the space of continuous curves taking values in $X$ --- though this forces $\gamma$ to be a continuous function.  Of course, other function spaces are also fine, but that's the most common in practice.)

Comment: But those random variables so have range in $X$, but the domain what it is? I mean, for every $t\in[0,1]$, $\gamma_t$ should go from a measurable space to another to be a random variable, where codomain here is $X$. But for the domain?

Comment: If you asked a probabilist, they might tell you the measurable space is irrelevant.  When you study probability theory, you see that this is partly true.  (If $\gamma$ is meant to be continuous, you can take $C([0,1];X)$ itself to be the measurable space and then the functions $\text{ev}_{t}: \gamma \mapsto \gamma(t)$ are continuous so measurable.)